# Powershell disk management

Tags: windows, powershell, disk

Welcome, I have question about managing disks via Powershell. Is there any possibility to e.g. change type of disk to dynamic, create mirrored disk, create raid-5 volume, extend volume via Powershell? I mean I need to do these things by using Powershell, NOT DISKPART!, but can't find solution.

Comment: "NOT DISKPART!" - what's wrong with diskpart? :)

Comment: It is for project and it has to be done in PS :/

Comment: Can't you get it done using `WMI`?

Comment: Only PS. I only received a tip to try using PSDrive, but I can't find any example of mirroring or changing type of disk.

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows Powershell Storage module? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/

Comment: Honestly I couldn't find there any command to change volume type or create mirrored disk etc. I mean those function which I need

Comment: You can call virtually any exe from a PowerShell script. See this... [PS Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) ...
[PowerShell to run old command-line tools](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters) - 
[Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
- So, ditto to what Mathias.

Answer (score 0):

[See these:](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20diskpart&form=ANSPH1&refig=b45bdb7e47064b398ea122c98de1e2f7&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20diskpart&sc=8-19&qs=n&sk=&cvid=b45bdb7e47064b398ea122c98de1e2f7)

> [Replace Diskpart With Windows Powershell – Basic Storage Cmdlets](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/replace-diskpart-with-windows-powershell-basic-storage-cmdlets)
>
> [Converting a DiskPart script to PowerShell on Windows Server 2012](https://blogs.perficient.com/2012/12/11/converting-a-diskpart-script-to-powershell-on-windows-server-2012)
>
> [step by step how to create a two way mirrored storage space via Powershell](https://charbelnemnom.com/2014/09/step-by-step-how-to-create-a-two-way-mirrored-storage-space-via-powershell-storagespaces-powershell/)

***Update***

As for ...

> 'any command to change storage type from basic to dynamic?'

Why are you trying to do this?

As per Microsoft, dynamic disk are depreciated, and we are to be using the [WSM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/vds-is-transitioning-to-windows-storage-management-api) -

> ***For all usages except mirror boot volumes (using a mirror volume to
>   host the operating system), dynamic disks are deprecated.*** For data
>   that requires resiliency against drive failure, ***use Storage Spaces***, a
>   resilient storage virtualization solution. For more info, see Storage
>   Spaces Technical Preview.
>
> You can continue to use DiskPart, DiskRAID, and Disk Management during
>   the deprecation period, but these tools will not work with Storage
>   Spaces or with any other new Windows Management Instrumentation
>   (WMI)-based Windows Storage Management APIs or in-box storage
>   management utilities or clients.

... and this the reason for no cmdlets for them exist or will.

Comment: Thanks, it is quite helpful, but do you know if there is any command to change storage type from basic to dynamic? It is needed to do some decent operations but anyway can't find it